# jquery 1.9 accordion height issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

I am using an accordion who's parent height is 400px. I want the accordion's height to never be greater than 400px, but I also want that the individual elements of the accordion adjust to the size of their content. I can get the whole accordion to be of height 400px by setting "heightStyle" to "fill." In this case each element of the accordion has a similar size, if the content of the element is larger than the default size it becomes scrollable, but if the content is smaller you get a lot of empty space, that I don't want.

Of course I can make each element the size of the content by setting "heightStyle" to "content," but in this case the expanded size of the accordion can be greater than 400px. So what I want is a combination of "fill" and "content," do you know how to get this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you would need is to set the max-height and overflow properties in the css. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/E3xnz/):

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I set the demo max-height to 200px just for demo purposes.

Comment: That worked, I had to adjust the max-height so that the total size of the accordion was 400px, since total accordion height is open content plus closed content header sizes. Much appreciated :)