# jQuery-ui Accordion height issue when embedded within a jQuery Tab

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

I have a jQuery tab, I have some tabs. I have a jquery-ui accordion with two panels, section 1 and section 2 in the first tab. Also another accordion with two panels in the second tab. For some reason, the panels' (divs within h3 tags) height for accordion on second tab are set to 0px and display:none and vertical scroll is appearing for both panels as i have seen with internet explorer debugger (see image attached in the link): http://snag.gy/6pmYd.jpg

The problem is only with the accordion on the second tab: panels are not resized to the tallest one. is it a bug of jQuery tab?

```
<style>
     /* IE has layout issues when sorting (see #5413) */
     .group { zoom: 1 }
</style>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#ComponentsTab">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="#OthersTab">Capsules</a></li>
  </ul>
<div id="ComponentsTab">

    <div id="accordion"> <!-- style= "width: 790px;" -->

        <div class="group">
            <!-- First Panel 'Add Component' -->
            <h3>Add component</h3>                    
                     <div>
                         @using (Html.BeginForm("AddField", "Configure", FormMethod.Post))
                         {
                             <label id="NumberOfItems" for="amount">@Resource.ComponentNumberOfItems</label>
                             <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />

                             <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
                             <div id="componentId">
                                 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ComponentViewModel.SelectedCompTypeId, new { @id = "componentIdLabel" })
                                 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ComponentViewModel.SelectedCompTypeId,
                                                       Model.ComponentViewModel.CompTypeItems)
                             </div>
                             <div class="componentGroup">     
                                 <label id="NameCompLabel" for="NameComp">Name:</label>                     
                                 @Html.TextBox("NameComp", null, new { @class = "textStyle" })
                             </div>
                             <div class="componentGroup">
                                 <label id="DescCompLabel" for="DescComp">Description:</label> 
                                 @Html.TextBox("DescComp", null, new { @class = "textStyle" })
                             </div>
                             <div class="componentGroup">
                                 <input id="submitAddComp" type="submit" value="@Resource.ButtonTitleAddComponent" />
                             </div>
                         }
                     </div> <!-- end first panel 'Add Component' -->
       </div> <!-- end group -->

       <div class="group">
             <!-- Second Panel 'Filter' -->
             <h3>Filters</h3>                                   
                     <div>
                        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Component",
                           new AjaxOptions
                           {
                               HttpMethod = "GET",
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                               UpdateTargetId = "jqGrid",
                               OnSuccess = "showGrid()"
                           }))
                        {
                        <!-- Drop down list for component types -->
                        <div id = "componentTypeFilter">                                        
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ComponentViewModel.SelectedCompTypeId, new { id = "componentFilterLabel" })
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ComponentViewModel.SelectedCompTypeId, Model.ComponentViewModel.CompTypeItems)
                        </div>
                        <!-- Apply filter button for components -->
                        <div id="ApplyFilterComponents" >
                            <input type="submit" name="_search" value="@Resource.CaptionComponentApplyFilter" />
                        </div>
                        }
                     </div>
        </div> <!--end group -->
    </div> <!-- end accordion -->
    <!--
    <div id="jqGrid">
        @Html.Partial("../Grids/_ComponentGrid")
    </div>
    -->
</div> <!-- End First tab -->
<div id="OthersTab">
    <div id="accordion2"> <!-- style ="width: 790px;" -->
        <div class="group">
                 <h3>Add others</h3>                     
                     <div>
                         @using (Html.BeginForm("AddOthers", "Configure", FormMethod.Post))
                         {
                             <div id="itemId">
                                 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ItemViewModel.SelectedItemTypeId, new { @id = "itemIdLabel" })
                                 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemViewModel.SelectedItemTypeId,
                                                       Model.ItemViewModel.TypeItems)
                             </div>
                             <div class="itemGroup">     
                                <label id="NameItemLabel" for="NameItem">Name:</label>                     
                                @Html.TextBox("NameItem", null, new { @class = "textStyle" })
                             </div>
                             <div class="itemGroup">
                                <label id="DescItemLabel" for="DescItem">Description:</label> 
                                @Html.TextBox("DescItem", null, new { @class = "textStyle" })
                             </div>
                             <div class="itemGroup">
                                <input id="submitAddItem" type="submit" value="@Resource.ButtonTitleAddItem" />
                             </div>
                         }
                     </div>
         </div>  <!--end group -->
         <div class="group">
                  <h3>Filters</h3>                     
                     <div>
                        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Items",
                           new AjaxOptions
                           {
                               HttpMethod = "GET",
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                               UpdateTargetId = "jqGridItems",
                               OnSuccess = "showGridItems()"
                           }))
                        {
                        <!-- Drop down list of item types -->
                        <div id = "itemTypeFilter">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ItemViewModel.SelectedItemTypeId, new { id = "itemFilterLabel" })
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemViewModel.SelectedItemTypeId,
                                                  Model.ItemViewModel.TypeItems)
                        </div>
                        <!-- Apply filter button for items -->
                        <div id="ApplyFilterItems" >
                            <input type="submit" name="_search" value="@Resource.CaptionItemsApplyFilter" />
                        </div>
                        }
                     </div>
          </div> <!-- end group -->
  </div> <!-- end accordion -->
  <!--
  <div id="jqGridItems">
    @Html.Partial("../Grids/_ItemsGrid")
  </div>
  -->
 </div> <!-- end second tab -->
</div> <!-- End tabs -->
```

**SCRIPTS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Slider functionality
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $(function () {
        $("#slider-range-max").slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 1,
            max: 255,
            value: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#amount").val($("#slider-range-max").slider("value"));
    });

    function showTabs() {
        $("#tabs").tabs ();
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        showTabs();
    });

        // Below makes tabs sortable (Their position can be altered)
    $(function () {
        var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
        tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
            axis: "x",
            stop: function () {
                tabs.tabs("refresh");
            }
        });
    });

        $(function () {
        function subscribe_accordion_to_hoverintent_event(accordionId) {
            $(accordionId).accordion({
                header: "> div > h3",
                event: "click hoverintent"
            });
        }

        subscribe_accordion_to_hoverintent_event("#accordion");
        subscribe_accordion_to_hoverintent_event("#accordion2");
    });

    // Collapse content
    $(function () {
        function set_accordion_as_collapsible(accordionId) {
            $(accordionId).accordion({
                collapsible: true//,
                //eightStyle: "auto"
            });
        }

        set_accordion_as_collapsible("#accordion");
        set_accordion_as_collapsible("#accordion2");
    });

    // Sortable functionality
    $(function () {
        function set_accordion_as_sortable(accordionId) {
            $(accordionId).sortable({
                  axis: "y",
                  handle: "h3",
                  stop: function (event, ui) {
                             // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
                             // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                             ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
                  }
            });
        }

        set_accordion_as_sortable("#accordion");
        set_accordion_as_sortable("#accordion2");
    });

    /*
    * hoverIntent | Copyright 2011 Brian Cherne
    * http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html
    * modified by the jQuery UI team
    */
    $.event.special.hoverintent = {
        setup: function () {
            $(this).bind("mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler);
        },
        teardown: function () {
            $(this).unbind("mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler);
        },
        handler: function (event) {
            var currentX, currentY, timeout,
                args = arguments,
                target = $(event.target),
                previousX = event.pageX,
                previousY = event.pageY;
            function track(event) {
                currentX = event.pageX;
                currentY = event.pageY;
            };
            function clear() {
                target
                  .unbind("mousemove", track)
                  .unbind("mouseout", clear);
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
            function handler() {
                var prop,
                orig = event;
                if ((Math.abs(previousX - currentX) +
                    Math.abs(previousY - currentY)) < 7) {
                    clear();
                    event = $.Event("hoverintent");
                    for (prop in orig) {
                        if (!(prop in event)) {
                            event[prop] = orig[prop];
                        }
                    }
                    // Prevent accessing the original event since the new event
                    // is fired asynchronously and the old event is no longer
                    // usable (#6028)
                    delete event.originalEvent;
                    target.trigger(event);
                } else {
                    previousX = currentX;
                    previousY = currentY;
                    timeout = setTimeout(handler, 100);
                }
            }
            timeout = setTimeout(handler, 100);
            target.bind({
                mousemove: track,
                mouseout: clear
            });
        }
    };

</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.elementStatus
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.image{
    /*float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-top: 1px; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 35px;*/
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.text{
    /*float: left;
    margin-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    width: 35%;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#accordion2 .ui-accordion-content 
{
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#accordion, #accordion2
{
    width: 790px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

#ComponentTypeFilterLabel
{
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 11px;
    float: left;
}

#componentTypeFilter, #itemTypeFilter
{
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-left: 12px; 
    float: left;
}

#ApplyFilterComponents, #ApplyFilterItems
{
    padding-left: 20px; 
    float: left;
}

#ApplyFilterComponents input, #ApplyFilterItems input
{
    margin-top: 22px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#NumberOfItems
{
    text-align: left; 
    width: 150px; 
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 1px; 
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#amount
{
    text-align: left; 
    color: #f6931f; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    border-top-color: currentColor; 
    border-right-color: currentColor; 
    border-bottom-color: currentColor; 
    border-left-color: currentColor; 
    border-top-width: 0px; 
    border-right-width: 0px; 
    border-bottom-width: 0px; 
    border-left-width: 0px; 
    border-top-style: none; 
    border-right-style: none; 
    border-bottom-style: none; 
    border-left-style: none; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-left: 1px; 
    width: 555px; 
    padding-top: 5px; 
    padding-left: 5px; 
    padding-right: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

#componentFilterLabel, #itemFilterLabel
{
    font-size: 1em;
}

#componentId, #itemId
{
    height: 55px;
    font-size: 1em;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#componentIdLabel, #itemIdLabel
{
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
    height: 21px; 
    margin-top: 25px;/*0px; */
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#NameCompLabel, #NameItemLabel
{
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-top: 25px; 
    padding-left: 14px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#DescCompLabel, #DescItemLabel 
{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#NameComp, #NameItem
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#DescComp, #DescItem
{
    float: left; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#submitAddComp, #submitAddItem
{
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.componentGroup, .itemGroup
{
    float: left;
}

.textStyle
{
    width : 150px;
}
```

this cause to make visible vertical scroll bars in each panel that I do not want that.

so If I uncheck those attributes from ie dev tools (debugger) then all panels will be set to the height of the tallest panel that is what i want. So how to set it in the divs? with inline style or css?

**ALMOST WORKING:**
I have upated my script, now it is almost working. What I have done is to modify the code inside  $(document).ready(...), see below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {            
            $("#accordion2").accordion({
                activate: function (event, ui) {
                    $(ui.newPanel).css('height', '100');
                    $(ui.newPanel).css('min-height', '100');
                    $(ui.newPanel).css('max-height', '400');
                }             
            }); // End Accordion
        } // End Activate tab
    }); // End tabs

    tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
        axis: "x",
        stop: function () {
            tabs.tabs("refresh");
        }
    });
});
```

The rest of code is kept the same as posted here above.

The problem now is the following: Initially first tab is active, and so first accordion shown with its first panel activated and expanded. Then when I switch to second tab, ONLY THE FIRST TIME, second accordion (accordion2) is show and its first panel activated, but the panel is not adjusting to its content: it is showing vertical scroll bar and i do not want that. Then If i switch to first tab and then again to second tab, then it works, accordion2 is activated and its first panel activated and shown, no vertical scroll bar is appearing and panel it is adjusting perfectly to its content. The problem is the first time i am switching from first tab to second tab where accordion2 is. So how to force panel for accordion2 to be adjusted to its content?

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#accordion2").accordion({
        header: "> div > h3",
        event: "click hoverintent",
        collapsible: true
    });

    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

and in css file:

```
#accordion2 .ui-accordion-content
{
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

**Please**, do not downvote!

Answer (score 10):

```
$("#DivName" ).accordion({
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
```

This is certainly what you and me are looking for. HeightStyle set to 'content' solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for height being set to 0 is because the other tabs are hidden and height gets calculated dynamically when accordion plugin is constructed. one way to solve the issue is use the tab activate event and construct the accordion only when the tab is active to the hight is set correctly. [JSFiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/8tBtR/

```
$(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      activate: function( event, ui ) {
          if((ui.newPanel.attr('id') === 'tabs-2') && (checkIfNotAccordion) )
          {
              $('#accordion2').accordion();
          }
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have included jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css by redmond theme,jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js so what's the problem? I think with these css and js are enough. Also why is another accordion (accordion2) that I have is working ok with two panels and accordion1 with also 2 panels is not working? why height for accordion1 is being set to 0px?

Comment: Please, see all my code here for a better understanding: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/setting-accordion-height

Comment: Ah..you are using it inside the a tab. The reason for height being set to 0 is because the other tabs are hidden. one way to solve the issue is use the tab activate event to construct the accordion.`$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      activate: function( event, ui ) {
          if(ui.newPanel.attr('id') === 'tabs-2')
          {
              $('#accordion2').accordion();
          }
      }`

Comment: I have checked what you say but it is not working, I have checked that when clicking on tabs-2 the tab activate event is raised but panels in accordion2 behave the same. The problem is that i am using a jquery tab, first accordion in first tab, the default selected tab, there is no problem as this is in the first tab and by default first tab is shown, the problem is with the rest of tabs as you have said but the solution you proposed does not work yet.I am using jquery 1.9.1

Comment: i have done what is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567171/heightstyle-fill-is-not-working-for-accordion-in-jquery and also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035117/jquery-1-9-accordion-height-issue but nothing is working for me... Any ideas?

Comment: I have checked your solution, yes it is working and this is what I want but for some reason in my code there is something that make panels for second accordion and second tab to appear as collapsible with a vertical scroll bar.... i do not know what is happening... i am going to paste my code here later.

Comment: Like i said because the tabs are hidden it will get height of 0. so you should not call the accordion plugin before the tab is active. I have take you code stripped of the razor code and made it work [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tBtR/). I have just introduced the activate event for tab and comments anything to do accordion2 in page load.

Comment: Your code works like a charm (but panels for accordion2 expand automatically on mouse over), but in my case, with razor code inside it is not working. It seems like razor code is causing all the problem. So how to make it works with razor code inside?A lot of thanks for you great support.

Comment: see my update post, from 'Almost working'. I explain now what i have done. Now it is almost working, I have modifying only function inside document ready. The problem is the first time i switch from 1st tab to 2nd tab. Panel is not being adjusted to its content by showing the vertical scroll bar. The rest of times, if i switch to 1st tab and then come to 2nd tab it is working. The issue is only happening the first time I switch from 1st tab to 2nd tab. Any ideas? it is almost working now ;)